# How to atomically update different databases?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, transactions, microservices

I have a lambda function which receives data of newly signed up users from a message queue and then inserts that data in two different databases.

Those two databases belong to two different microservices. First - users service which is using RDS postgres, and second - admin service whose database is basically a single DynamoDB table.

**I want to achieve "all or nothing" behavior for data insertions in the two databases - either insertion in both succeeds or both fails.**

- How can I have kind of an "atomic transaction" for inserting in the two databases, achieving "all or nothing" behavior?
- What if data gets inserted in admin service's DynamoDB table but fail to get inserted in users service's postgres table for some reason - how can I sort of rollback the insertion in DyanamoDB?

I may achieve this kind of functionality at code level but the code would be pretty messed up if let's say I have "all or nothing" insertions in 5 instead of 2 different databases.

I wonder if there is some standard way to have an atomic transaction like behavior when it comes to interacting with different DBs altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want a [distributed transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) which is actually quite complex problem in general. One of the popular approaches is to use [two-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) (2PC) which uses a [transaction manager/coordinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253836/whats-the-difference-between-a-transaction-coordinator-and-a-transaction-manage) (which can become a single point of failure). I don't know if AWS provides something out of the box which can coordinate distributed transactions between different DBs so if you will go with this route it is possible that you will need to implement one (as far as I can see both DynamoDB and RDS PostgreSQL support 2PC).

In microservice architecture using distributed transactions is relatively rare due to potential perfromance costs. More common approach is to "switch" to [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) and use for example something like [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html):

> A saga is a sequence of local transactions. Each local transaction updates the database and publishes a message or event to trigger the next local transaction in the saga. If a local transaction fails because it violates a business rule then the saga executes a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes that were made by the preceding local transactions.

For example in AWS you can implement [saga orchestration pattern with step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-serverless-distributed-application-using-a-saga-orchestration-pattern/).